# Are they the "same"? (Codewars)

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and I am doing some exercises from codewars. This is the description of the exercise. [Link to the exercise](https://www.codewars.com/kata/550498447451fbbd7600041c/train/python)

- Given two arrays a and b write a function comp(a, b) that checks whether the two arrays have the "same" elements, with the same multiplicities. "Same" means, here, that the elements in b are the elements in a squared, regardless of the order.
- If a or b are nil (or null or None), the problem doesn't make sense so return false.
- If a or b are empty then the result is self-evident.

There is like many tests in order to check if the code is correct, the thing is that I passed all of them except one. And it does not say the input used therefore it's difficult to see where is the problem.

This is my code:

```
def comp(array1, array2):

    if array1 == None or array2 == None:
        return False
    if array1 == [] or array2 == []:
        print ("a or b are empty or not empty lists.")
    
    if len(array1) != len(array2):
        return False
        
    array1.sort()
    array2.sort()

    if isinstance(array1, list) and isinstance(array2, list):
        for item in range(len(array1)):
            num_a = array1[item]
            num_b = array2[item]
            if num_b != num_a**2:
                return False
    return True
```

Comment: on code wars you can `print()` the input in the function to see it

Comment: Thanks for that quick response, I will try that now.

Comment: Hint: If you add a `print(array1)` and `print(array2)`into the code, then you'll be able to see the input, which can help you to track down the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is you're not accounting for negative integers correctly by `.sort()`ing. Here is a similar solution to yours doing that:

```
def comp(array1, array2):
    if array1 == None or array2 == None or len(array1) != len(array2):
        return False 
    array1.sort(key=abs)
    array2.sort(key=abs)
    return all(a**2 == b for a, b in zip(array1, array2))
```

Here's a clever solution I saw after solving the kata:

```
def comp(array1, array2):
    try:
        return sorted([i ** 2 for i in array1]) == sorted(array2)
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: Thanks, it was that. It's amazing how people can solve these problems with only a few lines.

Answer (score -1):

```
def comp(arr1, arr2):
    if arr1 is None or arr2 is None:
        return False
    if len(arr1)!=len(arr2):
        return False
    arr1.sort(key=abs)
    arr2.sort(key=abs)
    return all(arr2[i] == arr1[i] ** 2 for i in range(len(arr1))
```

Comment: This is a debugging question. Please address the question in the code rather than just posting your own solution.

Comment: Also make sure that your answer is unique. This doesn't look all that different than the 2020 answer.