# Are they the "same"? Codewars Kata

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, if-statement

I'm trying to solve the above-mentioned codewars kata with the following instructions:

Given two arrays a and b write a function comp(a, b) (orcompSame(a, b)) that checks whether the two arrays have the "same" elements, with the same multiplicities (the multiplicity of a member is the number of times it appears). "Same" means, here, that the elements in b are the elements in a squared, regardless of the order.

Examples
Valid arrays
a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]
b = [121, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]
comp(a, b) returns true because in b 121 is the square of 11, 14641 is the square of 121, 20736 the square of 144, 361 the square of 19, 25921 the square of 161, and so on. It gets obvious if we write b's elements in terms of squares:

a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]
b = [11*11, 121*121, 144*144, 19*19, 161*161, 19*19, 144*144, 19*19]
Invalid arrays
If, for example, we change the first number to something else, comp is not returning true anymore:

a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]
b = [132, 14641, 20736, 361, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]
comp(a,b) returns false because in b 132 is not the square of any number of a.

a = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]
b = [121, 14641, 20736, 36100, 25921, 361, 20736, 361]
comp(a,b) returns false because in b 36100 is not the square of any number of a.

Remarks
a or b might be [] or {} (all languages except R, Shell).
a or b might be nil or null or None or nothing (except in C++, Crystal, D, Dart, Elixir, Fortran, F#, Haskell, Nim, OCaml, Pascal, Perl, PowerShell, Prolog, PureScript, R, Racket, Rust, Shell, Swift).
If a or b are nil (or null or None, depending on the language), the problem doesn't make sense so return false.

This is my code, which is passing the initial tests but failing some tests later:

```
const comp = (a, b) => {
    function sortNumber(n1, n2) {
        return n1 - n2;
    }
    if (a === [] || b === [] || a === {} || b === {} || a === null || b === null) {
        return false
    } else {
        a = a.sort(sortNumber)
        b = b.sort(sortNumber)
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            if (Math.pow(a[i], 2) === b[i]) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The error message I'm getting is: It should work with random inputs too - expected false but got true (or viceversa). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you intend to return `false` for empty arrays, and what is the outer of the double loop for? Your loop variables have the same name, so all the outer one does is repeat the inner one for no apparent reason.

Comment: `a === [] || b === [] || a === {} || b === {}` - That's not how this works in JS. None of these comparisons will ever be true

Comment: You don't need to sort (which is an in-place operation so the assignment is a no-op) the arrays.

Comment: Calculating the power of `a[i]` for every element in `b` is a waste of performance. The value of `Math.pow(a[i], 2)` won't change - if `i` would be the correct one. Both loops use `i`

Comment: @Andreas Sorting seems like a performance-wise suboptimal solution, but quick&easy for ignoring the random order in the problem?

Comment: Your loop has `return` in every case - it returns after the first iteration.

Comment: @Andreas I think I need to sort the arrays because how could 121 from the first example array be equal to 121 * 121 from the second array? That's 11 * 11 but 11 is the last element in the second array, hence sorting... Also, in case of empty array or obj, I understood I have to return false, it's probably written in the wrong way but that's why I'm returning false.

Comment: @ASDFGerte You have to iterate over the complete array because of possible "holes" or numbers that have no counterpart so sorting doesn't help anything.

Comment: Can't you just `return false;` if you encounter any hole, or mismatching length?

Comment: Hint: `a.length === b.length && a.every(...)`

Comment: @ASDFGerte you're right about the loops using the same variable! Hadn't realised that, I'm gonna check it.

Comment: @Andreas about the sorting, check this if you understand the language used :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60003770/are-they-the-same-codewars